# The root's password is exposed in eshell

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I have defined the following alias in eshell:

```
 $ alias
 alias ff find-file $1
 alias l ls -l $*
 alias ll ls -l $*
 alias sudo *sudo $*
```

When i run "sudo ****" and input the root's password, the password is displayed completely.

Regards!

Comment: I hope that eshell doesnot display the entered password.

Comment: When you run `sudo` in the eshell, what is the prompt that gets displayed asking for the password?

Answer (score 4):

Chances are, the regexp that is being used to look for the password prompt isn't set up properly for your situation.

Try the following:

```
(require 'comint)
(setq comint-password-prompt-regexp
      "\\(\\([Vv]erify\\|[Oo]ld \\|[Nn]ew \\|'s \\|login \\|\
Kerberos \\|CVS \\|UNIX \\| SMB \\|^\\)\
\\([Pp]assword\\|Verify\\\\|密码)\\( (again)\\)?\\|\
pass phrase\\|\\(Enter\\|Repeat\\|Bad\\) passphrase\\)\
\\(?:, try again\\)?\\(?: for [^:]+\\)?:\\s *\\'")
```

Note: I just took the value for `comint-password-prompt-regexp` and added the characters you said were your prompt.